# Prove non-homogenous $\frac{a}{b+c^2}+\frac{b}{c+a^2}+\frac{c}{a+b^2} \ge\frac{9}{3+a+b+c}.$

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c>0$ then prove $$\frac{a}{b+c^2}+\frac{b}{c+a^2}+\frac{c}{a+b^2} \ge\frac{9}{3+a+b+c}.$$
It was [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1308376p7001254) by NguyenHuyenAG.

This problem is very hard to me because it's non-homogenous cyclic inequality. I thought of BW but nothing left.

Also, by Cauchy-Schwarz $$\frac{a}{b+c^2}+\frac{b}{c+a^2}+\frac{c}{a+b^2} \ge\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca+a^2b+b^2c+c^2a} \ge\frac{9}{3+a+b+c}.$$
which is not true for all $a,b,c>0.$

I hope there is a proof which might be motivated by computer but easliy verified by hand.

Any ideas and comments are welcome.

Comment: BW works well, right? After full expanding, let $a = c  + s, b = c + t$?

Comment: I'll try more. Thank you.

Comment: I think Holder helps.

Comment: Did you try BW and work it out?

Comment: I try by hand but it's not easy

Comment: OK. So if we can use computer, BW kills it. If you do BW by hand, it is not easy.

Comment: I agree. Is BW ugly ? (by computer).

Comment: It is nice (all coefficients are non-negative). Sometimes, BW can be not nice e.g. when some coefficients are negative (so BW can be very complicated).

Comment: I got it. You can share it to us. I'll post my Holder proof later. (it quites long but smooth)

Comment: I will not post it since it is not nice by hand. I just to clarify your sentence "I thought of BW but nothing left." (I don't know you do it by hand.)

Comment: Alternatively, we may use C-S via the form $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (c^2+b)a(a+b+c/2)^2$. Then use BW. It is not much better than direct BW.

Comment: @RiverLi It is also my approach. The rest is proving two inequality: one homogenous and non-homogenous. I'll try more to prove it.

Comment: @RiverLi Now I proved it  without BW. Hope there is no mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a}{b+c^2} \cdot \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a(b + c^2)(b + 3)^2
\ge [a(b + 3) + b(c + 3) + c(a + 3)]^2.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$[a(b + 3) + b(c + 3) + c(a + 3)]^2 \ge \frac{9}{3 + a + b + c}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a(b + c^2)(b + 3)^2$$
or
\begin{align*}
 &{a}^{3}{b}^{2}+2\,{a}^{3}bc+{a}^{3}{c}^{2}+{a}^{2}{b}^{3}-4\,{a}^{2}{b
 }^{2}c-4\,{a}^{2}b{c}^{2}+{a}^{2}{c}^{3}+2\,a{b}^{3}c\\
&\qquad -4\,a{b}^{2}{c}^{
  2}+2\,ab{c}^{3}+{b}^{3}{c}^{2}+{b}^{2}{c}^{3}+6\,{a}^{3}b-3\,{a}^{3}c+
 15\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-18\,{a}^{2}bc\\
 &\qquad +15\,{a}^{2}{c}^{2}-3\,a{b}^{3}-18\,a{
  b}^{2}c-18\,ab{c}^{2}+6\,a{c}^{3}+6\,{b}^{3}c+15\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}-3\,b{
  c}^{3}\\
 &\qquad +9\,{a}^{3}-36\,{a}^{2}b-9\,{a}^{2}c-9\,a{b}^{2}+108\,abc-36\,a{
  c}^{2}+9\,{b}^{3}-36\,{b}^{2}c-9\,b{c}^{2}\\
 &\qquad +9\,{c}^{3}+27\,{a}^{2}-27\,
 ab-27\,ac+27\,{b}^{2}-27\,bc+27\,{c}^{2}\\
 &\ge 0.
\end{align*}

The left is smooth. We may use BW (Buffalo Way).

Answer (score 1):

**Proof.**

By using Holder inequality as $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c^2}\cdot\sum_{cyc}a(b+c^2)(2a+2b+c)^2\ge \left(2\sum_{cyc}a^2+3\sum_{cyc}bc\right)^2,$$it's enough to prove $$\left(2\sum_{cyc}a^2+3\sum_{cyc}bc\right)^2(3+a+b+c)\ge 9\sum_{cyc}a(b+c^2)(2a+2b+c)^2.$$
We'll prove two inequalities
$$\left(2\sum_{cyc}a^2+3\sum_{cyc}bc\right)^2\ge 3\sum_{cyc}ab(2b+2a+c)^2 \tag{1}$$
$$(a+b+c)\left(2\sum_{cyc}a^2+3\sum_{cyc}bc\right)^2\ge 9\sum_{cyc}c^2a(2b+2a+c)^2 \tag{2}$$

Due to homogenous inequality, assuming that $a+b+c=1$ and let $ab+bc+ca=q;abc=r.$

---

*Proof of $(1).$*

Notice that,
$$\left(2\sum_{cyc}a^2+3\sum_{cyc}bc\right)^2=(2-q)^2,$$
$$\sum_{cyc}ab(2b+2a+c)^2=4q-11r.$$

Thus, $(1)$ becomes $$(2-q)^2\ge 3(4q-11r) \iff 33r+4-16q+q^2.$$
By Schur of third degree $9r\ge 4q-1,$ we obtain $$ 33r+4-16q+q^2\ge  33\cdot \frac{4q-1}{9}+4-16q+q^2=\frac{1}{3}(1-q)(1-3q)\ge 0.$$

Hence, we prove $(1)$ is true.

---

*Proof of $2.$*

Notice that$$(a+b+c)\left(2\sum_{cyc}a^2+3\sum_{cyc}bc\right)^2=(2-q)^2,$$
$$ \sum_{cyc}c^2a(2b+2a+c)^2=\sum_{cyc}c^2a(2-c)^2 =4\sum_{cyc}a^2b-4\sum_{cyc}a^3b+\sum_{cyc}a^4b.$$
Also, $$\sum_{cyc}a^3b=\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}a^2b-\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2-abc\sum_{cyc}a=\sum_{cyc}a^2b-q^2+r.$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{cyc}a^4b&=\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}a^3b-\sum_{cyc}a^2b\sum_{cyc}ab+abc\sum_{cyc}ab\\&=(1-q)\sum_{cyc}a^2b-q^2+(1+q)r.
\end{align*}
Thus $$\sum_{cyc}c^2a(2b+2a+c)^2=(1-q)\sum_{cyc}a^2b+3q^2+(q-3)r.$$

Using the well-known result $\sum_{cyc}a^2b+abc\le \dfrac{4}{27}(a+b+c)^3,$ it's enough to prove $$(2-q)^2\ge 9\left[(1-q)\left(\frac{4}{27}-r\right)+3q^2+(q-3)r\right]$$
$$\iff 9(2-q)r+\frac{8}{3}-\frac{8}{3}q-26q^2\ge 0.$$
We may consider two cases

+) $1\ge 4q$ then $$\frac{8}{3}-\frac{8}{3}q-26q^2\ge 0.$$
+) $1\le 4q$ then by Schur of third degree $9r\ge 4q-1$ and $1-3q\ge 0,$ we obtain

$$9(2-q)r+\frac{8}{3}-\frac{8}{3}q-26q^2\ge(2-q)(4q-1)+\frac{8}{3}-\frac{8}{3}q-26q^2=\frac{2}{3}(17q-2)(1-3q)\ge 0.$$

Hence, the proof of $(2)$ is done.

We end proof here. Equality holds at $a=b=c>0.$

Comment: Very nice to split into two inequalities. Also, you give another Holder.

Comment: It's same as yours in the comment above. I just proved it.

Comment: Oh, I see it now.